# Match all number occurrences without any letter following or preceding

Tags: javascript, regex

What I'm trying to accomplish:

Assuming an example string:

```
1 this is a1 my test 1a 12 string 12.123 whatever 1
```

I would like to have a Regex, that would give me all the occurrences of numbers (floats included), but I want it to skip the number if a letter (or more generally: non-number) precedes or follows it. So `a1` and `1a` would not match.

I've been struggling with this for a while, I got to this point (not ideal, because it also catches the preceding space):

```
/(^|\s)\d*\.*\d+/g
```

But this will also catch the `1a` instance... I could also set up something similar, that would skip `1a`, but would catch `a1`...

Can I accomplish this using regex matching?

Comment: How about... positive and negative numbers `+1` or `-1`? Exponential notation `1e1`? digit separator `1,000,000.00` or `1 000 000`?

Comment: I don't really need exponential notation for this one. Digit separator would indeed be a cool addition (obv aside from spaces, cause these should be treated as separate numbers in that case).

Comment: The problem with finding a number in a sentence is that you don't know if a dot is a period or a float notation.

Comment: Not really, if the dot is immediately followed by a digit, then it's quite clear it should be treated as a number. Otherwise, it would be followed by a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use word boundaries with this regex:

```
/(?:\.\d+|\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9QEDH8/1)

Comment: "floats included": does not match `1.4e5` and false positive for floats without spacing in between: https://regex101.com/r/9QEDH8/2

Comment: And you can include signed numbers also e.g. `-1.23` in not match. I can surely address it if OP has any of those requirements.

Comment: [`[+-]?(?:\.\d+|\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:e\d+)?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/9QEDH8/3) should work for these cases.

Comment: Very nice.. I was just playing devil's advocate, but I still don't know if those last two should match since they're not separated by spaces.

Comment: This expression can match numbers like **20**.42word: https://regex101.com/r/vQtY8N/1

Comment: @vianov: We can tweak it by using `(?:\.\d+|\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b(?!\..)`

Answer (score 0):

For a simple, but not comprehensive solution (assuming numeric types used in the given example string, no negative numbers,scientific notation,etc.,), try this:

```
\d*\.*\d+
```

It removes the `\s` from your regex you developed, which matches the preceding space.

`\d*` will match all of the numbers (digits [0-9]).

Adding `\.*\d+` will match floats (decimal followed by digits [0-9]).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a regex-only answer but maybe that's a good thing, we'll see.

The regex in use here is `/^[-+]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\d*\.\d+)(?:e\d+)?$/`:

```js
var testStr = '.1 this is a1 my test +5 1a 12 string -2.4 12.123 whatever . .02e1 5e5.4 1 1.4e5 1.2.3';

console.log('matches');
console.log(...testStr
  .trim()
  .split(/\s+/g)
  .filter(word => /^[-+]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\d*\.\d+)(?:e\d+)?$/
    .test(word)
  )
);

console.log('mismatches');
console.log(...testStr
  .trim()
  .split(/\s+/g)
  .filter(word => !/^[-+]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\d*\.\d+)(?:e\d+)?$/
    .test(word)
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression: `(?<=^|\s)[-+]?(?:[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)(?=$|\s)` - [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ALPh5o/8)

JavaScript supported: `(?:^|\s)([-+]?(?:[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+))(?=$|\s)`  - [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ALPh5o/6)

This expression supports floating-point numbers with an optional sign.

JS does not support positive lookbehind, so it was replaced by non-capturing group. The numbers are captured by the 1st group.